# VueJS Axios Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, axios

I am using [this][1] tutorial to create a Google Map and now I want to make a GET request with Axios:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/mapjson").then(function(response) { })
```

to use the data of my json file in the map (coordinates, polylines etc).

The problem is that everything inside the axios function is not defined! For example I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at eval

Is there any way to use this Google Map code inside my Axios function? I need to pass  latitude, longitude and a date/time object.

Comment: can you post your axios request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `const map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);` creates a `map` variable that is local to the `mounted` hook. If you want to access `map` in another function of the component, add it in the `data` property and use `this.map` instead.